# How to apply group by instead of distinct when need only unique rows?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities

I am working on ASP.NET Razor page LINQ to SQL function. I face issue I can't display distinct rows from result returned for `viewmodel AssetLPOvm`

**Desired result**

If I have 2 or 3 rows as sample exactly every thing is same and repeated so I need to return only one rows unique or distinct because other rows is repeated .

So exactly I need to return distinct result using group by instead of distinct.

I tried using distinct as below but it not return distinct rows.

So what I do to solve issue?

```
    public List<AssetLPOvm> GetAllLpoDetails(string SelectedCompany)
    {    
        var AssetBranches = _unitOFWorkAsset.AssetBranches.GetList(x => x.CompanyNo == SelectedCompany && Convert.ToInt32(x.UserID) > 0 );
            
        var NewAssetTagging = _unitOFWorkAsset.NewAssetTagging.GetList(x => x.LPONo > 0);
var result = (from assetBranch in AssetBranches
               join user in Users on assetBranch.UserID equals user.UserID
               join assetTagging in NewAssetTagging on Convert.ToDecimal(assetBranch.LPONO) equals assetTagging.LPONo
     
               select new AssetLPOvm
               {
                   AssetItemNo= assetBranch.AssetItemNo,
                   SupplierName=assetTagging.SupplierName,
                   SelectedMCUName= assetBranch.SelectedMCUName,
                   AssetOwner=assetBranch.AssetOwner,
                   ItemCode=assetBranch.ItemCode,
                          
                   Qty = assetBranch.Qty,
                   LPONO = assetBranch.LPONO
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
 return result;
}

    public class AssetLPOvm
    {    
        public string LPONO { get; set; }

        public string AssetItemNo { get; set; }

        public string SupplierName { get; set; }

        public string SelectedMCUName { get; set; }

        public string AssetOwner { get; set; }

        public double Qty { get; set; }

        public string ItemCode { get; set; }


    }

    public class AssetBranches
    {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public decimal ID {get;set;}
      public string AssetItemNo { get; set; }
      public string SelectedMCUName { get; set; }
      public string AssetOwner { get; set; }
      public double Qty { get; set; }
      public string LPONO { get; set; }
      public string ItemCode { get; set; }

       }
    public class NewAssetTagging
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public decimal? LPONo { get; set; }
        public decimal? SupplierNumber { get; set; }

    }
public class User
{
    public string vLoginName {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

How to make group by to result of function instead using distinct function?

I try with distinct but not return distinct rows.

Comment: thanks for support you group by Itemcode but i need to group by all columns not item code only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by all columns , you can have a try:

```
.GroupBy(p => new {
    p.AssetItemNo,
    p.SupplierName,
    p.SelectedMCUName,
    p.AssetOwner,
    p.ItemCode,
    p.Qty,
    p.LPONO}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason `.Distinct()` did not work as expected is that your `AssetLPOvm` class does not implement `IEquatable<T>`. The equality comparison used by `.Distinct()` then only performs a *reference comparison*, not a *value comparison*. Two different `AssetLPOvm` objects will always compare unequal, even if they have the same values. The result is that no de-duplication is performed.

This can be resolved by:

1. implementing `IEquatable<T>`.
2. Select the values into an *anonymous object* (which will implement a value base comparison), apply `.Distinct()`, and then use `.Select()` to convert to `AssetLPOvm` objects.
3. Use `.DistinctBy()`, which allows you to explicitly define the values to be compared.

Try replacing the `.Distinct()` with:

```
.DistinctBy(a => new { a.AssetItemNo, a.SupplierName, a.SelectedMCUName, a.AssetOwner, a.ItemCode, a.Qty, a.LPONO})
```

I believe clearly shows the original intent, while avoiding the extra overhead of `.GroupBy()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use GroupBy as below.

```
.GroupBy(x=>x.ItemCode).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList()
```

Comment: thanks for support you group by Itemcode but i need to group by all columns not item code only